# Permutations of capitalization

Tags: c#, .net, string, capitalization

I want to build a list containing every possible permutation of capitalization of a word. so it would be

```
List<string> permutate(string word)
{
    List<string> ret = new List<string>();
    MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
    return ret;
}
```

So say I put in `"happy"` I should get an array back of

```
{happy, Happy, hAppy, HAppy, haPpy, HaPpy ... haPPY, HaPPY, hAPPY, HAPPY}
```

I know of plenty of functions that will capitalize the first letter but how do I do any arbitrary letter in the word?

Comment: I just have to wonder what this is for. If it's for any kind of comparison purpose, it's probably the wrong way to approach the problem.

Comment: That may be for a dictionary attack.

Comment: Actually it is, I forgot my password to a file, I know the word but not the capitalization.

My plan is to calc every possable one and feed it in to a dictionary cracker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify individual characters if you convert your string to an array of char. Something like this should do the trick...

```
public static List<string> Permute( string s )
{
  List<string> listPermutations = new List<string>();

  char[] array = s.ToLower().ToCharArray();
  int iterations = (1 << array.Length) - 1;

  for( int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++ )
  {
    for( int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++ )
    array[j] = (i & (1<<j)) != 0 
                  ? char.ToUpper( array[j] ) 
                  : char.ToLower( array[j] );
    listPermutations.Add( new string( array ) );
  }
  return listPermutations;
}
```

Comment: I added a listPermutatuions.Add before the loops so it would store a fully lowercase version, other than that yours works perfectly.

Comment: This won't return all of them though. For example, "haPpY". In fact, there should be 2^n of them total, whereas the code above only produces n(n+1)/2 + 1 of them.

Comment: And this is why you should always test your code ... and why open source works so well. Thanks newacct. I actually took the time to test the implementation this time... and it does indeed produce all 2^n permutations.

Comment: What if I only wanted casing variations for certain characters in the string?  For example, consider a string "abcd" and I only wanted casing varions for "bd", I would get "abcd", "aBcd", "aBcD", and "abcD".  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that while the accepted answer is the most straightforward way of capitalizing an arbitrary letter, if you are going to change the capitalization repeatedly on the same set of letters (e.g., 32 times in "happy" and growing exponentially for longer words), it will be more efficient to turn the string into a char[], set the appropriate letter(s), and construct the string from the array.

Comment: Which makes me wonder... what if you created a two-dimensional array, with index 0 being the word in lowercase and index 1 being the word in uppercase (as char arrays). Then you could iterate from 0 to 2^(word_length-1) and use the bits of the integer to tell you which array to grab each letter from. I really have no idea if this is a good idea or not. It just came to me when I read this.

Comment: Conceptually I did just that (the bit-testing part), but I modified a single array in place.  Better still is to use a Gray code so that the entire array can be generated with 2^(word_length)-1 "case flips."

Comment: What would be the benefit of using a GrayCode?  Is flipping only one bit per iteration more efficient?  How would you go about using a gray code?  Using the regular binary encodings of integers is easy because you can just use bitwise operations to check which bits are set in the int, but how would you be able to get the GrayCode bitstring for each int

Answer (score 1):

To "permute" your string (technically, this isn't permutation since you're not changing the order of anything, but I don't want to be seen as an an*l-retentive :-), I would use a recursive approach, which basically "permutes" the string minus the first character and attaches those to the upper and lower variations of that character.

Something like (in C, my C# is not really up to par so you'll have to convert it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void permute (char *prefix, char *str) {
    char *newPrefix;

    /* End of string, print and return. */

    if (*str == '\0') {
        printf ("%s\n", prefix);
        return;
    }

    /* Allocate space for new prefix. */

    if ((newPrefix = malloc (strlen (prefix) + 2)) == NULL) {
        printf ("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* Do lowercase/sole version and upper version if needed. */

    sprintf (newPrefix, "%s%c", prefix, *str);
    permute (newPrefix, &(str[1]));

    if (islower (*str) {
        sprintf (newPrefix, "%s%c", prefix, toupper(*str));
        permute (newPrefix, &(str[1]));
    }

    /* Free prefix and return. */

    free (newPrefix);
}
```

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *str, *strPtr;

    /* Check and get arguments. */

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("Usage: permute <string to permute>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((str = malloc (strlen (argv[1]) + 1)) == NULL) {
        printf ("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy (str, argv[1]);

    /* Convert to lowercase. */
    for (strPtr = s; *strPtr != '\0'; strPtr++)
        *strPtr = toupper (*strPtr);

    /* Start recursion with empty prefix. */

    permute ("", str);

    /* Free and exit. */

    free (str);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this as `"permute Pax1"` returns:

```
pax1
paX1
pAx1
pAX1
Pax1
PaX1
PAx1
PAX1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a console app that does this..

```html
 public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter string");
        string value = Console.ReadLine();

        value = value.ToLower();

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

         var results =
             from e in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << value.Length)
             let p =
             from b in Enumerable.Range(0, value.Length)
             select (e & (1 << b)) == 0 ? (char?)null : value[b]
             select string.Join(string.Empty, p);

        foreach (string s in results)
        {
            string newValue = value;
            s.ToLower();
            foreach(char c in s)
            {
                var Old = c.ToString().ToLower();
                var New = c.ToString().ToUpper();
                newValue=ReplaceFirstOccurrence(newValue, Old, New);
            }
            list.Add(newValue);
        }

        foreach(string s in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string ReplaceFirstOccurrence(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
    {
        int Place = Source.IndexOf(Find);
        string result = Source.Remove(Place, Find.Length).Insert(Place, Replace);
        return result;
    }    
}
```

I got a list of all possible subsets of characters in the string then for each character in each subset, replaced them with their capital counterparts in the initial string, then made a list of those. Had to have a custom Replace function as the normal string.Replace would replace any occurrence of the character.

It's probably not the cleanest of code, but it does the job. This got brought up as a means of dynamically searching over encrypted fields, and I wanted to see how crazy that would really be..

Answer (score 1):

If *order* doesn't matter, you can try *Linq*. We enumerate all binary numbers in a range of `[0..2**word.Length]`. and treat each number as *mask*: `0` - lower case, `1` - upper case. For instance for `happy` we have

```
mask      string
----------------
00000  ->  happy
00001      Happy
00010      hAppy
00011      HAppy
00100      haPpy
00101      HaPpy
...
11111      HAPPY
```

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  List<string> permutate(string word) =>
    Enumerable
      .Range(0, 1 << word.Length)
      .Select(mask => string.Concat(word.Select((c, i) => (mask & (1 << i)) == 0 
         ? char.ToLower(c) 
         : char.ToUpper(c))))
      .ToList();
```

**Demo:**

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", permutate("happy")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
happy, Happy, hAppy, HAppy, haPpy, HaPpy, hAPpy, HAPpy, hapPy, HapPy, hApPy, HApPy, haPPy, HaPPy, hAPPy, HAPPy, happY, HappY, hAppY, HAppY, haPpY, HaPpY, hAPpY, HAPpY, hapPY, HapPY, hApPY, HApPY, haPPY, HaPPY, hAPPY, HAPPY
```

Answer (score 0):

Loosely speaking, something like below.  I may have my ranges off by one, but the idea is sound.

```
def cap_n(in_str, pos):
  leading = in_str.substr(0, pos-1)
  trailing = in_str.substr(pos+1) # no second arg implies to end of string
  chr = in_str[pos].to_uppercase()
  return leading + chr + trailing
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise operations. For a word of length N you need an integer type represented by N bits. If the word is longer - split it. Iterate through values from 0 to 2<sup>N</sup>-1 and examine each bit from 0 to N-1. If the bit is 1 - upcase ( `Char.ToUpper()` ) the letter corresponding to that bit.

This approach is better that a recursive algorithm since it is not prone to stack overflows on long words.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1) You don't care too much that this is O(n*2^n)... although I'm curious to know: what is the best asymptotic run time for this type of problem?

2) Your input is all lowercase.

3) Your input is < 32 characters long. (# of usable bits in the permutation counter, i)

```
    List<string> permutate(string word)
{
    List<string> ret = new List<string>();

// MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
Dictionary<char,char> toUppers = new Dictionary<char,char>(26);
toUppers.Add('a', 'A');
toUppers.Add('b', 'B');
toUppers.Add('c', 'C');
toUppers.Add('d', 'D');
toUppers.Add('e', 'E');
toUppers.Add('f', 'F');
toUppers.Add('g', 'G');
toUppers.Add('h', 'H');
toUppers.Add('i', 'I');
toUppers.Add('j', 'J');
toUppers.Add('k', 'K');
toUppers.Add('l', 'L');
toUppers.Add('m', 'M');
toUppers.Add('n', 'N');
toUppers.Add('o', 'O');
toUppers.Add('p', 'P');
toUppers.Add('q', 'Q');
toUppers.Add('r', 'R');
toUppers.Add('s', 'S');
toUppers.Add('t', 'T');
toUppers.Add('u', 'U');
toUppers.Add('v', 'V');
toUppers.Add('w', 'W');
toUppers.Add('x', 'X');
toUppers.Add('y', 'Y');
toUppers.Add('z', 'Z');

char[] wordChars = word.ToCharArray();
int len = wordChars.Length;

// iterate the number of permutations
for(int i = 0; i < 2^len; i++) {
    char[] newWord = new char[len]();

    // apply "i" as a bitmask to each original char
    for(int n = 0; n < newWord.Length; n++) {
        if((1 << n) & i != 0) {
            newWord[n] = toUppers[wordChars[n]]; // or skip the dictionary and just call Char.ToUpper(wordChars[n])
        } else {
            newWord[n] = wordChars[n];
        }
    }
    ret.Add(new String(newWord));
}

    return ret;
}
```

Note: I haven't compiled or tested this code.  This is also implementing the bitwise compare that sharptooth suggested above.